# use java code instead of mapstruct expression

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I am learning to use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

I have the following custom mapping configuration that maps a `List` comes from JPA entity to DTO `String` that way:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StatusMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "statusCode",
            expression = "java(entity.getStatuses().get(entity.getStatuses().size() - 1).getStatus())")
    @Mapping(target = "details",
            expression = "java(entity.getStatuses().get(entity.getStatuses().size() - 1).getMessage())")
    StatusResponse map(MyEntity entity);
}
```

My problem with this solution is that the Java code in the `expression` actually is a string and the IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) is not checking the syntax of this "java" code.
Maybe after a refactor this piece of code will not work anymore because I renamed the related field.

And if I add a `null` check to the expression then this piece of code will be more longer, and longer code can have more typos.

Can I write here somehow a real java code instead of using this Java expression string?

Comment: "Maybe after a refactor this piece of code will not work anymore because I renamed the related field" write unit tests for that case

Comment: and of course you can (flushing "expressions" down...): https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that MapStruct is an annotation processor, and the expression written in `expression` will be written one to one in the generated Java class. Therefore, doing a refactoring will lead to a compile error.

Having said that there is an alternative solution for this.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StatusMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "statusCode", source = "statuses", qualifiedByName = "statusesStatus")
    @Mapping(target = "details", source = "statuses", qualifiedByName = "statusesMessage")
    StatusResponse map(MyEntity entity);

    @Named("statusesStatus")
    default String extractStatus(Collection<Status> statuses) {
        return statuses != null && statuses.isEmpty() ? statuses.get(statuses.get() - 1).getStatus() : null;
    }

    @Named("statusesMessage")
    default String extractStatusMessage(Collection<Status> statuses) {
        return statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty() ?  statuses.get(statuses.get() - 1).getMessage() : null;
    }
}
```

Doing this will make sure that MapStruct uses the custom methods that you have defined.

---

Another potentially nice solution (which does not yet exist in MapStruct) and for which there is an open feature request is [Allowing indexing for object list](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1321).

The potential solution for that can look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StatusMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "statusCode", source = "statuses[-1].status")
    @Mapping(target = "details", source = "statuses[-1].message")
    StatusResponse map(MyEntity entity);
}
```

If this is something that is interesting for you, I would suggest voting on that issue.